# Chromecast "Audio" not found by pulseaudio-dlna on 16.04

Tags: sound, google-chrome, pulseaudio, android

I have a brand spanking new Chromecast Audio.  I can cast to it from my Android phone using cast-enable apps like Spotify and Pandora.  I can also cast to it from my Android phone using the awesome AirAudio app.

I can cast to the Chromecast Audio from Ubuntu 16.04 using either (A) Chrome's google cast plugin; or (B) `mkchromecast`.  But the former is inconvenient (no media key support) and the latter seems to have huge latency issues (around 27 seconds) -- and it is also seems to require WiFi as opposed to allowing an ethernet connection.

**What I can't do**, is find the Chromecast Audio using `pulseaudio-dlna`.  `Pulseaudio-dlna` simply does not see the Chromecast at all.  This is unexpected because the pulseaudio-dlna **does find** my AVR receiver and my DirecTV receiver.  And as noted above, other Ubuntu apps **can find** the Chromecast Audio.  After reading the usage notes for `pulseaudio-dlna`, I checked for a firewall issue -- but the Ubuntu 16.04 computer does not have the firewall on.

Any ideas what is going wrong here?

(I tried posting an issue on the pulseaudio-dlna github page, but those are not generally answered.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by resetting the router that was between my primary router and the computers that were failing to connect to the Chromecast Audio with `pulseaudio-dlna`.  Some setting in the router (other than firewall) must have conflicted with `pulseaudio-dlna`.

That said, there is *something* in `pulseaudo-dlna` that operates differently than Google Chrome's casting plug-in and `mkchromecast`.  Both of those worked under the old router setup.

Also, it may be notable that `mkchromecast` did not work with `pulseaudio-dlna` installed.  So there may be more than one conflict.

[My primary problem now is major lag that seems to grow from about 2 seconds at the start of listening to Pandora/Pithos, to about 25 seconds after about an hour of listening.]

Answer (score -2):

I resolved the issue on this link [a bug report](https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna/issues/236) and stopping the Linux firewall.